# How do I stop my iPhone from asking to upgrade to iOS 10?

Tags: iphone, ios

It's super annoying. My iPhone 5 was dog slow after iOS 9. I don't want to waste my time with iOS 10.

Comment: You can't sadly

Answer (score 4):

I know you won't like this answer, but you can't. Apple wants you to update to the latest version.